# Search and autocomplete username from active directory into ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I'm trying to list down and autocomplete the user name from the active directory.
Can someone look into my code and tell me what's the issue ?
Please forgive me if the question is even wrong.

**view**

```
<input asp-for="User.Username" value="@ViewBag.Username" class="form-control" data-url="/ajax/user" />
<span asp-validation-for="User.Username" class="text-danger"></span>

//script to autocomplete
<script>
    _af.push(() => {
        $('#User_Username').autoComplete();
    });
</script>
```

**First Method**

```cs
[HttpPost] //this to pull the username from AD
public JsonResult findit(string prefixText)
{
    DirectoryEntry directory = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=x,DC=y");
    string filter = "(&(name=" + prefixText + "*))";
    string[] strCats = { "name" };
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    DirectorySearcher dirComp = new DirectorySearcher(directory, filter, strCats, SearchScope.Subtree);
    SearchResultCollection results = dirComp.FindAll();
    foreach (SearchResult result in results)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry prop in result.Properties)
        {
            if (prop.Key.Equals("name"))
            {
                System.Collections.IEnumerable propsEnum = prop.Value as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
                foreach (object individualValue in propsEnum)
                {
                    if (individualValue.ToString().IndexOf(prefixText) != 0)
                    {
                        items.Add(individualValue.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Json(items.ToArray();
}
```

**Second Method**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IFormCollection col)
{
    string username = col["user.username"].ToString().Normalize();
    var testa = findit(username);
    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NormalizedUsername = testa);//here the issue                     
    if (user == null)
    {
        user = new User
        {
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
            NormalizedUsername = username.Normalize(),
            Username = $"{username[0].ToString().Trim().ToUpper()}{username.Substring(1)}"
        };
        _context.Users.Add(user);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: 'here the issue' what issue? No user returned? Exception thrown? Something else?

Comment: in the below code the error is "cannot implicity convert type json result to string; what im trying to do is when i type  a name like erik; it will search the name in findit method and complete the name.

Comment: var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NormalizedUsername = testa)

Comment: `findit` returns an array of suggested/matching users, but you are trying to put that `json` result (e.g.: `{users: [{id:1,name:"Erik"}]}`) into your query string. Also it seems this wont fit to your `_context.Users.FirstOrDefault(...)` logic, since this would only return one user - i guess you want multiple suggestions for your autocomplete, if more then one user is named "Erik". Something like `_context.Users.Where(x => someUserNameArray.Contains(x.NormalizedUsername))` should work in this case.